# How Do I Trigger A Build In Azure DevOps On Commit To Branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If I was using TeamCity I could trigger my build when there is a commit to a particular branch:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-vcs-triggers.html

The closest I can see in the documentation for Azure DevOps is to trigger a build from a [pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)

Is it possible to configure the pipelines in Azure DevOps to trigger a build when there is a commit to `develop` or `master`?

Comment: Not get your latest information. If danielorn's answer is helpful for you, you could consider to accept it as answer. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It an be done, both for pipelines defined in [yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#branches) as well as [classic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#branch-filters) pipelines defined in directly in the UI of Azure Devops.

## Triggers in Yaml pipelines

Add a `trigger` block to the top of your `azure-pipeline.yaml` (or whatever your yaml file you have hooked up to your pipeline) and put the following content.

```
trigger:
- master
- develop
```

## Triggers in Classic pipelines

1. Open up the pipeline in edit mode
2. Select "Triggers" in the top menu
3. Check the box `Enable continuous integration`
4. Fill in the branch filters
   [image]